# How to run windows C++ project on Mac

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I am currently making a school project and my team are all using Windows, I am the only one with a Mac. The project does not seem to run on my computer. Here's what I tried:

1. I tried running it on VS Code but, I get some x86 architecture error (symbol not recognized)
2. I tried running on Xcode, but the project is pretty long and it will be hard to convert and re-convert .h files to .hpp and vice-versa
3. I stumbled upon Clion but when I try to open the project on Clion, the run button is greyed out and it seems I need a CMakeLists.txt file but I do not know how to configure it. I've seen some configurations of the file like so:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
   project(HelloWorld)

   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

   add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)
   ```

My issue with this is that the project has multiple drivers and in this above example, there's only 1 executable, but I guess I need multiple executable.

How can I configure my CMakeLists.txt to run C++ on Mac? Clion would be preferred but if there is any other way of collaborating on a cross platform Windows/Mac project please let me know

EDIT:

So here's how my project is structured:

3 Folders : Drivers, Resources, Game

-Drivers contain 4 cpp files that each contain a main() function.

-Resources contains some .txt and .map files

-Game contains the necessary classes for the game class.

Essentially, the Drivers are used for the teacher to test out our functions of the classes inside the Game folder.

EDIT 2:
Here is the error from the console

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "OrdersList::deleteOrder(int)", referenced from:
      _main in OrdersDriver.cpp.o
  "OrdersList::printOrders()", referenced from:
      _main in OrdersDriver.cpp.o
  "OrdersList::move(int)", referenced from:
      _main in OrdersDriver.cpp.o
  "OrdersList::addOrders(Orders*)", referenced from:
      _main in OrdersDriver.cpp.o
```

Comment: Oh.... Ouch... If you make use of any of the windows API functions -- it will not work on Mac (unless you are running a copy of windows in VirtualBox on Mac). The problem is that the Windows API and the Mac GUI are completely different. If the class uses a cross-platform gui toolkit, like Qt or Gtk (I don't know if WxWidgets works on Mac), but then you can use common code with GUI features. If you are just working on terminal apps -- then most things should work (obviously windows specific features like high precision timer, filesystem API, etc.. still won't work)

Comment: its just a terminal app

Comment: They might be using conio.h -- Again, Windows specific. We would need more details to answer your question: What exactly error did it give you when you tried to compile it? What header files are missing? Also: .h and .hpp files should be interchangeable(using c++; can't use .hpp with C).

Comment: No, even if there are multiple source files, you simply compile the supporting source files to object files and link the object files together into a single executable. You should work on understanding how to compile and link from the command line, so you understand how compilation works -- then you can tell CMake or any other IDE how you want it to compile your code. Otherwise, you are just fighting with some other automation tool trying to get it to compile your code -- in a way you don't yet understand. You will find using the command line to compile is quite easy -- and FAST.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide the compiler's error logs. You can also give a link to the GitHub page but I'm not sure whether your classmates would be ok with that.

Comment: What IDE do they use?

Comment: Quick mentioning you don't need to convert between `.h` and `.hpp` files.